# Forge viewer 3ds Max Viewport

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I'm testing out a new workflow with 3ds Max and my model/scene keeps loading in Top view when I translate it into the Forge viewer. I've tried to save the view as a perspective view but I'm still getting the same result in the viewer. In Revit I remember that I could choose the view from the Collaboration settings. How would I modify the view in 3ds max? I'm translating a MAX file. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3ds Max does not have the same idea of a "named 3d view" like Revit does. 3ds Max mainly stores geometry in it's global space, in it's scene file (.MAX). It is also saving the viewport configuration (so on load you can have same view(s)), but the idea of named 3d views is not there for the model derivative service translator.

This means you may have to reorient the geometry in the scene, before sending to the translator to get the desired resulting orientation. Or you can orient the view using the viewer to get the correct starting view if that is the issue. For example, to orient the view, you could do this on viewer start:

```js
var front = new THREE.Vector3(0, -1, 0);
viewer.navigation.setPosition(front);
viewer.fitToView (true) ;
```

Note that 3ds Max has an "Export to LMV SVF" in it's desktop export options. This can be a nice way to test without sending to the model derivative service. You can export to SVF locally, then using the Forge Viewer you can view the local model (I use firefox as it does not complain about cross-origin error in the local disk load). Again, this is nice testing scenario when working with 3ds Max scenes to understand the translator behavior. Hope it helps, kevin

Comment: Thanks for your help. You're also mentioning that I can orient the view using the viewer to get the correct starting view. That's actually the issue. How would I go about managing this?

Comment: I added a simple example to original answer. Hope it helps, kevin

Comment: thanks! I've added a comment to denis' answer below. Do you know how I can modify the view in a FBX exported from 3ds Max?

Answer (score 1):

To have a control on what view will be set as default/home view when opening a translated .max file, in 3ds Max follow these steps:

1. Remove all cameras from the scene, if any.
2. Select the perspective view, rotate, pan, zoom, in other words position the view as you wish, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to create a Physical Camera From View.
3. Select the Front View, go to Create -> Cameras -> Free Camera and click on Front View (anywhere) to create the Free Camera.

Now if you translate the .max file with this setup, the Camera you create at step 2 will be set as the default/home view.

I recently wrote a blog post on this trick: [Control the default view when translating 3ds Max files](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/control-default-view-when-translating-3ds-max-files)

Comment: thanks. I now know how to modify the .MAX camera view, but do you also happen to know how I can modify a view for a FBX exported file from 3ds Max? I've tried different settings but I keep getting the same camera every time and it doesn't corencpondence with any of my viewport views inside 3ds Max.

Comment: I have to check that, but I think you could at least try deleting all cameras except the one you need, and the translator will have to choose that one. Just speculation, but I will look into that.

Comment: yes I've tested different cameras (single and combinations) to try to find the pattern, but with no luck yet. Thanks a bunch for checking!