# Model orentation/view translating MAX files

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

**GOAL:**
Our goal is to load a translated `.MAX` file in `perspective` view.

**WHAT HAPPENS:** The translated .MAX files chooses the following view from the view selections inside 3ds Max, and loads the model in `top` viewport and `top` orientation:

[image]

**SIMILAR QUESTION:** A [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885531/forge-viewer-3ds-max-viewport/48930466#48930466) question has been asked, though there's a slight variation in our situation. We learned in that question that we can orient the starting view but our objective is to modify the main scene/view.

**ONE SOLUTION:** Is to manipulate the top/top view by rotating this view to have it look like a perspective view, and the model loads in seemingly a perspective view - but it still retrieves the `top` orientation, which results in wrong behavior when we navigate/orbit the model.

We would preferably have the viewer to pick the lower right view from the viewport selection illustrated above (`perspective`) - as we have found it will choose the upper left view (top/top) every time. We've tried to change this view from "top" to perspective and saved a new "home"-state on the view cube, like this:

[image]

But it still sets the view and orientation to `top`. Any guidance would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I rolled back your edit (it's still visible in the [history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49155220/revisions)) -- the question should remain just a question, though you are welcome to post an answer of your own and even accept it if you like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a control on what view will be set as default/home view when opening a translated .max file, in 3ds Max follow these steps:

1. Remove all cameras from the scene, if any.
2. Select the perspective view, rotate, pan, zoom, in other words position the view as you wish, then press Ctrl+C to create a Physical Camera From View.
3. Select the Front View, go to Create -> Cameras -> Free Camera and click on Front View (anywhere) to create the Free Camera.

Now if you translate the .max file with this setup, the Camera you create at step 2 will be set as the default/home view.

I just finished writing a blog post on this trick. You can find it [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/control-default-view-when-translating-3ds-max-files).

Comment: Hi Denis, thanks for reaching out and thanks for your thoroughly reply. Amazing! We've tried every camera setting in there but all we got was this weird angled object rotation which you also described in your blog post. For future readers, this solution from Denis solved the problem:

Select the Front View, go to Create -> Cameras -> Free Camera and click on Front View (anywhere) to create the Free Camera.

Thanks a bunch. I updated the question with your solution.

Comment: Hi Denis. Update, now it seems like some of you developers have been making some improvements to this topic, as of now we won't need the Free Camera on the Front view anymore